# In my Todo App the adding todo function is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

here is the code of add todo function

```js
const addtodo = (req, res) => {
  const { item } = req.body;
  const email = req.session.user.email;
  lists
    .create({ item, email })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result + " added");
      return res.redirect("/");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

In the above code "lists" is a table in database that will contain the list of items that will be added in the todo app. And I'm using SQLite for this.

Am I'm doing anything wrong here? I looked at the various site but not getting the solution

Below is the error message that I am getting in console

```
errors: [

    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'lists.edit cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'edit',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [lists],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'lists.done cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'done',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [lists],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, You need to be much more specific about what is not working. Any error or output in console? What is `lists` and what does `lists.create` function do? Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'lists.edit cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'edit',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [lists],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    },
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'lists.done cannot be null',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'done',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: [lists],
      validatorKey: 'is_null',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Molda I am getting this in my console.log

Comment: That didn't help really. **What is the `lists` variable? What library are you using to query the db? What db are you quering?**

Comment: As it says very clearly, "lists" has some required fields for creating an entity. Take a look at your model declaration and see what "edit" and "done" are.

Comment: Just a hunch, maybe you need `{ ...item, email }` instead of `{ item, email }`?

Comment: @Molda lists is a table in the database that will contain the list of all items of todo and I'm using SQLite

Comment: You are still not answering my question. While `lists` could be a name of the table in db, I asked specificaly what is the `lists` variable --> `lists.create...` What does the create function do? `lists` is probably an instance of something. How did you define the `lists` variable??? Is the `create` function provided by some library(npm package?)? I'm asking about the variable because it is mentioned in the error and until i know what it is it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Molda lists.create will insert a new row in the list table. It is used in SQLite JS. 
For more clarification you can also visit the github repo  https://github.com/sujata13/To-do-App

Comment: lists.create is used in sequelize for inserting rows

Comment: Finaly some useful informations. So your problem is that you defined your lists to have `done` and `edit` properties which can't be null but not passing them in the create function. Easy fix `lists.create({ item, email, edit: false, done: false })...`

Comment: @SujataMishra Welcome to stackoverflow. While asking questions make sure there is no missing point in your code or question texts. If you show a variable, put some code or explanation to describe what it is exactly.

Comment: @Molda Thanks!!! It's working now :)